# Outbound SMTP through Google Apps: Rejected Connection

Tags: email, smtp

When I try to set up my SMTP through our Google Apps, I keep getting errors:

> Failed to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 [SMTP: Failed to
>   connect socket: Connection refused (code: -1, response: )]

I have tried all the different ports and also a personal Gmail account. I've seen other questions and how Google puts a cap on email campaigns. We are planning on using our existing Mailchimp for mass emailing. This is also a new installation. Any ideas how to connect?

Comment: Gmail needs a certain combination of settings to work. Check [this answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/45990/15929) for details that worked in 2023.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear to be an authentication issue, it appears to be a network issue. Do you have a firewall on the server, or between the server and the Internet that could be blocking your outbound request to port 465?

Comment: Our server hosting is a GoDaddy Linux server with cPanel, so unfortunately I'm not sure. I just tried setting up one of the free emails that came with the server so I could try out a different SMTP server besides Google App's, but I got the same error.

Comment: I think you should ask GoDaddy about any default firewall settings on the server, or other firewalls between your server and the public Internet.

Comment: Well I figured out a workaround. I set up a local email address through GoDaddy's cPanel and named it No Reply. The SMTP works through that and I set CiviCRM to show up as our Google Apps email. Thanks anyway, Paul!