# SMTP with Gmail and App Password: Civi says success, but it's not sent

Tags: email, smtp, google, outbound-email

This works:

- I have Civi set up to send email through my personal Google account (using an App Password because I use 2FA). This works, but the emails have **my** address as sender, of course, which we want to fix.

This does not work:

- My organisation also uses Google, and my account also uses 2FA, and I have also created an App Password - just as with my personal account.
- In CiviCRM, in the SMTP settings, I *only* replace the SMTP username and SMTP password, switching from my personal data to the organisation data.
- Sending a test email causes **CiviCRM to report "OK", but that test email never arrives.**
- Switching back to my personal account data and sending a new test email is successful: CiviCRM gives the same confirmation *and that email arrives.*
- Despite everything seeming identical, **what am I missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I needed to **set up a new user account in our Google organisation** and use that in CiviCRM. Now it works. Here are the steps I did:

*Note: English settings might be named a little different than given here; our CiviCRM is set to German so I translate onthe fly.*

1. create new user account in our Google organisation.
2. Gmail settings > Forwarding and POP/IMAP > turn on POP access. (Mark Gmail's copy as read.)
3. Google account settings > security > turn on "less secure app access".
4. CiviCRM > Admin > CiviMail > Sender address > enter email address of Gmail account.
5. CiviCRM > Admin > CiviMail > Mail accounts > edit default account:

   1. name = Gmail
   2. server = pop.gmail.com
   3. username = email address of Gmail account
   4. password = password of Gmail account (just the regular password, not some app-specific one, because we chose to use "less secure app access".)
   5. local part = leave empty
   6. email domain = the part after @ in the email address of Gmail account
   7. return path = leave empty
   8. protocol = POP3
   9. mail folder = leave empty
   10. use SSL = turn checkbox on
   11. use for = bounce

With these settings, the button "save and send test mail" resulted in a successful alert in CiviCRM, and the email was indeed sent to the test recipient.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check email permissions in your organization Google Workspace for the email account you switch to and see the "From Email Address Options" CiviCRM page ("Administer > Communications > FROM Email Addresses")